# Create array function jQuery

Tags: jquery, dry

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.authority-email', function() {

    var authorityValues = $(this);

    var authorityArray = [].map.call(authorityValues, function (authorityValues) {
        return authorityValues.value;
    }).join(',');

    $('input#team_authority_emails').val(authorityArray);
});

$(document).on('change', 'input.member-email', function() {

    var memberValues = $(this);

    var memberArray = [].map.call(memberValues, function (memberValues) {
        return memberValues.value;
    }).join(',');

    $('input#team_member_emails').val(memberArray);
});
```

My thoughts are that this process isn't very DRY and could be a single separate function?

```
[].map.call(memberValues, function (memberValues) {
  return memberValues.value;
}).join(',');

var authorityArray = [].map.call(authorityValues, function (authorityValues) {
  return authorityValues.value;
}).join(',');
```

What is the best way to create a function that can create and return my array? Or are there any other improvements I can make to this?

Comment: What's the point of using the `map` method here? There is only one element! Why not simply `this.value`?

Comment: The user can add as many emails as they require. So potentially there can be an infinite amount of input fields with the following class `input.member-email`. The database expects the values (emails) returned in the following format: abc@email.com, abd@email.com, etc. The values are returned to a hidden field.

Comment: I see what Vohuman is saying - inside the handler function `this` is going to only equal the value that changed, not the full set of values.

Comment: Yep just tested this and it is only returning the value that changed not the full set as you say. How would I get the full set in the function you mentioned below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you want to perform a one-way binding.

All of the values from a set of inputs are to be mapped to a specified single input.

Here is a solution:

```
function bindValuesToTarget(sourceSelector, targetSelector) {
    var writeValuesToTarget = function() {
       var valuesString= [].map.call($(sourceSelector), function (arrayItem) {
           return arrayItem.value;
       }).join(',');

       $(targetSelector).val(valuesString);
    }        

    $(document).on(
      'change',
      $(sourceSelector),
      writeValuesToTarget
    );

    // You might want to do this the first time, 
    // just in case it never changes
    writeValuesToTarget();
}

bindValuesToTarget('input.member-email', 'input#team_member_emails');
bindValuesToTarget('input.authority-email', 'input#team_authority_emails');
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I am after. Although 1 problem. The user can add as many emails as they require. So potentially there can be an infinite amount of input fields with the following class `input.member-email`. The database expects the values (emails) returned in the following format: abc@email.com, abd@email.com, etc. The above only returns a single email each time it is run, unlike my current implementation that will return every email a@email.com, b@email.com, etc

Comment: @ThomasTaylor - I've rewritten the answer. I think this matches what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you, it was my silly mistake calling `this`. Also added the missing comma after the `$(sourceSelector)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('input', 'input.authority-email', function() {
    var valCommas = this.value.replace(/\s+/, ",");  // "a,b,c,foo,bar"
    $('#team_authority_emails').val( valCommas );
});
```

replaces one or more spaces with a single comma